# VBA: Writing a CopyAndPaste Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a `CopyAndPaste` function and tried to call the function from `Main`. However, there is an error at:

```
CopyAndPaste(ThisWS,FromRange,ThisWS,ToRange,False)
```

> Compile Error
>   Expected: =

May I know why is this happening?

```
Sub Main()

Dim ThisWS As Worksheet, FromRange As Range, ToRange As Range

Set ThisWS = ActiveSheet
Set FromRange = Range("I6")
Set ToRange = Range("M6")

CopyAndPaste(ThisWS,FromRange,ThisWS,ToRange,False)

End Sub    


Function CopyAndPaste(RefSheet As Worksheet, RefRange As Range, ToSheet As Worksheet, ToRange As Range, _
                      Optional HLink As Boolean)

RefSheet.RefRange.Copy Destination:=ToSheet.ToRange

If HLink = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=ToSheet.ToRange, _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:=RefSheet.Name & "!" & RefRange.Address, _
        ScreenTip:="Click to view details", _
        TextToDisplay:=""
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `CopyAndPaste ThisWS, FromRange, ThisWS, ToRange, False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers seem to treat the parentheses as a mere cosmetic detail. They're not.

I can't reproduce your exact compile error, but your code is invalid. Here's a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that explains what's going on:

#### Valid Code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Test Nothing
End Sub

Function Test(foo As Object)
End Function
```

#### Invalid Code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Test (Nothing) ' compile error: invalid use of object
End Sub

Function Test(foo As Object)
End Function
```

The only difference is the parentheses. So what do these parentheses do exactly?

> This is confusing, why not just use parentheses?
>
> *Parentheses force VBA to evaluate the value of the bracketed expression, and pass the result ByVal to the called procedure.*

The parentheses basically mean "evaluate this expression as a value" - and we're trying to do that with an object reference, known at compile-time: VBA refuses to proceed, and complains.

It's even more obvious with multiple parameters - what should VBA evaluate this expression to?

```
(Sheet1, Thisworkbook, Nothing)
```

- When calling a `Sub` procedure, parentheses must never be supplied.
- When calling a `Function` procedure, parentheses must be supplied whenever the function's return value is not discarded.

In other words, it's not *forbidden* to have a `Function` procedure with `Sub` procedure semantics (i.e. no return value, side-effecting).

#### *Semantically* Correct Code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Debug.Print Test(Nothing) 'parentheses required because we're using the returned value
End Sub

Function Test(foo As Object) As String
    'compute something using foo, return a value
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Mat's Mug, I learn something new. Will study deeper into this Parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few variables which you are passing (but not really needed).

1.Once you define and set **FromRange** from **ThisWS** worksheet, there is no need later on to use `RefSheet.RefRange` you can just use `RefRange`.

2.Since you are not returning anything from **CopyAndPaste** it should be a regular Sub (doesn't have to be a function).

3.Not sure you have 1 sheet or 2, as ***RefSheet*** and ***ToSheet***  are the same, since they are both getting the passed argument ***ThisWS*** (worksheet).

```
Sub Main()

Dim ThisWS As Worksheet, FromRange As range, ToRange As range

' it's better if you used instead something like Set ThisWS = Sheets("YourSheetName")
Set ThisWS = ActiveSheet
Set FromRange = ThisWS.range("I6")
Set ToRange = ThisWS.range("M6")

CopyAndPaste FromRange, ThisWS, ToRange, False

End Sub


Sub CopyAndPaste(RefRange As range, ToSheet As Worksheet, ToRange As range, _
                      Optional HLink As Boolean)

RefRange.Copy ToRange

If HLink = True Then
    ToSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=ToRange, _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:=RefRange.Parent.Name & "!" & RefRange.Address, _
        ScreenTip:="Click to view details", _
        TextToDisplay:=""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `SubAddress:=RefSheet.Name` - where's `RefSheet`? Use `RefRange.Parent.Name` instead ;-)

Comment: Thanks, forgot i removed that extra parameter (whic according to the sample code, is unnecessary)

Comment: Should `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add` be `ToRange.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add`?  (And ToSheet is not required to be passed as a parameter, as it doesn't get used.)

Comment: And the SubAddress should possibly be coded as `SubAddress:="'" & RefRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & RefRange.Address` so that sheet names that have embedded spaces don't cause the link to break.

Comment: Thanks everyone. In the sample I set it to be in the same worksheet to test the program in a simple way. The actual work will most likely to be in different sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Functions should not be used to change other cells, but rather to calculate and return a value.

Make your routine a sub, not a function. Then call it without the braces.

Comment: *User-Defined Functions* (UDF) [called by a cell formula] can't change other cells; "normal" functions *shouldn't* change cells (or have any side-effects), but very well *could*.

Comment: I'm not sure about "functions shouldn't have side effects" - one might choose to program that way, but using a function to do something *and* return a value is more natural to me than using a Sub with a ByRef parameter

Comment: @TimWilliams not even in a fluffy, pink-coated, marshmallow-smelling, unicorn-populated world where all the code is *perfect*?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - seems like once you get beyond "working" then "perfect" is often a matter of opinion  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to complete my program due to everyone's help. Here are my codes. Feel free to use it.

```
Sub Main()

Dim FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet As Worksheet
Dim FromRange As Range, ToRange As Range

Set FromSheet = Worksheets(1)
Set ToSheet = Worksheets(2)
Set FromRange = FromSheet.Range("E10:E15")
Set ToCell = ToSheet.Range("N2")

CopyAndPaste FromRange, ToCell, True

End Sub

Public Sub CopyAndPaste(FromRange As Range, ToCell As Range, Optional HLink As Boolean)

If HLink = True Then

Dim FromCell As Range, R As Long, C As Long

R = FromRange.Rows.count
C = FromRange.Columns.count

    For C = 0 To C - 1
    For R = 0 To R - 1

        ToCell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=ToCell.Offset(R, C), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & FromRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & FromRange.Rows(R + 1).Columns(C + 1).Address, _
            ScreenTip:="Click to view Sheet: " & FromRange.Parent.Name, _
            TextToDisplay:=FromRange.Rows(R + 1).Columns(C + 1).Value
    Next R
    Next C

Else

FromRange.Copy ToCell

End If

End Sub
```